# ssis reuse object variable ResultSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

i use an Execute SQL Query Task to get a ResultSet into an object variable in SSIS.
However if another task uses this ResultSet within a foreach loop and a 2nd task wants to use the same ResultSet afterwards it seems to be empty. I figured out that it seems to be empty because the pointer remains at the end of the Resultset after first use.

Is there any possibility to move the pointer to the beginning againt?

Comment: While your attempt to keep your code concise is admirable, why not just use a second object variable or repopulate the object instead?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Multicast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137701.aspx) task to copy the same data to multiple destinations.